# Are there any lightweight OPC servers which can have multiple instances running on the same machine?

Tags: opc

I am wanting to run performance testing of an OPC client to 100 servers but I do not want to run 100 machines

Is there any way to set this up for testing purposes?

Comment: Do you need OPC-UA or OPC-DA servers?

Answer (score 0):

If they are OPC-DA (or A&E, HDA) servers, and you are really interested in just the performance of the client part, and do not mind actually using a single OPC server that just "looks" like 100 of them, there is a chance that you can use the following trick:

1. Using REGEDIT, under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, find an entry with the ProgID of your server. Its purpose is to point to the server's CLSID.
2. Make 100 copies of this entry, each time giving it a different ProgID, but pointing still to the same CLSID.
3. Configure your client to connect to 100 different OPC server, using the ProgIDs you created.

If you client uses just ProgIDs for recognizing the "identity" of the server, it will think it is connecting to 100 different servers, and it will treat them as such, i.e. create 100 separate connections. If the client, however, first converts the ProgID to CLSID, it will see the same CLSID, and it won't work. Obviously, even if this works, the performance test will be skewed as far as the server side is concerned, because there will be just 1 server process, not 100 of them.

Note that CLSID cannot be changed in this way, because it is also hard-coded in the COM class factory inside the server.

Another wild idea that comes to my mind is to use a product such as OPC Tunneler (e.g. MatrikonOPC). In this product you can create any number of "servers", which in fact connect by tunneling to a true OPC server somewhere else. Therefore you might be able to configure 100 tunnels (looking like separate servers), all connecting to 1 target OPC servers.